# Why was this question locked?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This question: [How is pitch changed and lift generated in QNET VTOL (Vertical Take off & Landing)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/640397/how-is-pitch-changed-and-lift-generated-in-qnet-vtol-vertical-take-off-landin) , has been closed as off-topic (seems reasonable since it's not about EE), and then locked - presumably by the same mod who closed it and added a comment "Being migrated to Aviation".
At the time I'm looking at it, the question is 8 hours old, and this comment is at least 3 hours old - does migration take some time?

*But in any case - why was it locked?*

The [help page for locked posts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) lists a number of reasons for locking - but I don't see any reason which would apply here.
There doesn't appear to have been an 'edit war', there's certainly nothing 'controversial' about the question.
Was there 'extended bickering in comments' which has now been deleted? Seems unlikely that this question would have lead to that kind of thing ...

Update - now it's been re-opened and immediately re-closed by a different mod ... ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: I reopened and then closed it so that I could then migrate it again. It again showed locked BUT it has now been migrated. || Mission accomplished  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's locked it was going to be moved to aviation.se, it might be waiting approval usually migrations happen in a short amount of time

A community bot locked it, but it doesn't list a reason

Answer (score 1):

Update: Migration was subsequently successful.

---

Strangely, it is shown as being closed and migrated by Voltage Spike, BUT I closed it and initiated migration. Presumably we did so almost n parallel with Voltage Spike's actions occurring seconds before mine.

I did not lock it (and VS didn't either).
Whether migration occurs is to be seen.